# Howto log to 2 instances of same type of sink (Seq)?

Tags: serilog, seq, seq-logging

Possible? 
Cannot find a "sink forwarder", where one sink can forward to several other sinks, possibly of the same type.

Serilogs documentation (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings)
clearly states that

***NOTE: When using serilog:* keys need to be unique.***

so adding the same Seq sink several times doesnt seem to be a good idea.

I'm looking for the same concept as in log4net, where one logger can hold several appenders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `<appSettings>` config provider for Serilog doesn't support this case; the `appSettings.json` one does, if you're able to use it, otherwise configuring the sinks in code `WriteTo.Seq(...).WriteTo.Seq(...)` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Semi-workaround style of solution:

1. Put a "read these keys" in appsettigs

Example 1: Read one key

```
<add key="SerilogToHttpKeys" value="MyMachineA" />
```

Example 2 (which solves the problem): Read many keys

```
<add key="SerilogToHttpKeys" value="MyMachineA, MyLocalMachine, MachineOnTheMoon" />
```

Both cases "points" to an unlimited number of keys, that are then read via code (see 2) and hence be tweaked w/out recompiling

```
<add key="MyLocalMachine" value="http://localhost:5341/;juzOPqqqqqqqq" />
<add key="MyMachineA" value="http://10.107.14.57:5341/;m8QVnDaqqqqqqqqqqqqq" />
<add key="MachineOnTheMoon" value="http://10.107.14.62:5341/;Ah0tSzqqqqqqqqqqqq"
```

2. Loop the keys in code - each key points to a http address with an API key, which is used for logging to Seq, but change the structure of each entry, and you could log to file ect.

   ```
    foreach (var aKey in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SerilogToHttpKeys")
                               .Split(',')//Use , as separator 
                               .Select(s => s.Trim()))
    {
        var    fields    = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(aKey);
        var    separator = ';';
        string serverUrl = fields.Split(separator)[0];
        string apiKey    = fields.Split(separator)[1];

        loggerConfiguration = loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Seq(serverUrl: serverUrl, apiKey: apiKey);
    }
   ```

I use this for logging both to my server and my dev machine at the same time - its easier to keep the localhost Seq open when errors occour, and see if I can find them there instead of logging into the server. However, in case my devmachine is not online, I have the logs on the server as well. Off course, if more than one persons accesses the server licenses are needed for Seq, but in a simple "one dev, one dev-machine, one server" it works.